# How can I add a tab to Storybook

Tags: storybook

I would like to find an addon that I can put another story in essentially so I can show off the HTML/CSS only version of a component, instead of the web component version.

Anyone heard of ideas on how to add more details to a page?

I've looked into just adding it as another story and having it that way but the context doesn't make much since, and we already have 2 story books one for angular and one for web components I don't want to maintain a 3rd for html/css